# Login script with PHP and mySQL - lock pages if not logged in using cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication

I created a login script (with much help of a tutorial) that protects the maintenance parts of my website. It works and when there's a succesful login, cookies are made. The problem is that the used tutorial offers a way to check if there are (valid) cookies saved on the users computer for the pages that are meant only for registered people, but it results in nothing (so probably an error). I can't find what's wrong, so I hope you can help me fixing it. Cookies stay for half an hour by the way.

```
<?php

// connect to db
include('connect.php');

// page of login script, used when no/wrong cookie is found
$login_pagina = "login.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$_COOKIE['username']."'";
$resultaat = mysql_query($sql) OR die ("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
$aantal = mysql_num_rows($resultaat);
if ($aantal == '0') {
// cookie and databasevalues are not the same
echo "Click <a href=\"".$login_pagina."\">here</a> to login.";
} else {
$login = mysql_fetch_object($resultaat);
if ($_COOKIE['password'] != $login->password) || ($_COOKIE['username'] != $login->username)) {
echo "Cookies couldn't be combined";
} else {
echo "you're logged in!";
}
}

?>
```

(As the tutorial was in Dutch I translated the comments and some text. Some variables are still in Dutch, but I think it's clear enough.)

Comment: Not sure where the tutorial is from but first off doing `$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='".$_COOKIE['username']."'";` is not a good idea - read -> http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Neither is storing the password in a cookie

Comment: salted password as md5 is ok as a cookie (it's not clear in the script)

Comment: @ManseUK Oops, that's something I should have realised. Fortunately things are not running yet: I don't want to think about hackers uploading files etc. to my server. How would you do it keeping things safe?

@steveo225 Thanks for mentioning! I'll probably throw this script away. But how could I create a "stay logged in during X amount of time"-system then?

@Mario Lurig I don't think the script is creating salted password as md5 cookies: `setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time() + 30*60);
setcookie("password", $_POST['wachtwoord'], time() + 30*60);`

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to recheck the script for look-alike errors, but I'm not sure whether this is the right place to have it checked...

Answer (score 0):

So you get a blank page?
No output at all?
If so , there's must be an error , try enabling error_display (check your php.ini file).

Few things:
1. The query is checking if the cookie's value is a username in the "members" table.
So make sure that it contains members.
2.Use firebug or chrome to check if the cookie is really exists and if its value is a member's username.
5.Instead:

```
$login = mysql_fetch_object($resultaat);
if ($_COOKIE['password'] != $login->password) || ($_COOKIE['username'] != $login->username)) {
```

Try: (The condition need to be "AND" not "OR" ... there's no logic if not)

```
$login = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat);
if ($_COOKIE['password'] != $login['password']) AND ($_COOKIE['username'] != $login['username']) {
```

1. replace: if ($aantal == '0') {
   ($aantal == 0) {
   It's not an error but still , this function return a number , so treat it as a number.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have PHP errors enabled on my server by now which is indeed easier when you're developing. The script mentioned above has been trown away. We've chosen a safer (md5 passwords etc.) and better one which does work. So I'm afraid your help isn't necessarry anymore for this particular script. Though I appreciate your reply and I can of course use the advice in new developments!